# How do I iterate on a collection when I don't know what the upper limit of iterations is?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have an API that I am pulling data from, and I want to collect all the tags from this API...but I don't know the number of tags in advance, and the API throttles access via the max number of results returned in any 1 call (100). It has an unlimited number of pages though.

So a call may look like this: `Tag.update_tags(100, 5)` where `100` is the max number of objects returned in 1 call and `5` is the page to begin (i.e. if you assume that the tags are stored sequentially, what this is saying is return the tag records with IDs in the range of `401 - 500`.

The issue is, I don't want to manually have to enter `5` (i.e. I don't know what the upper limit is). There is no way for me to ping the total number of tags (if there were, I would simply divide it and put this call in a loop up to that number).

All I do know is that once it reaches a page that doesn't have any results, it will return an empty array `[]`.

So, how do I loop through all the tags and stop when the result returned is an empty array (which would be the final result returned and therefore not evaluated)?

What does that loop look like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use an unconditional loop with a break statement when the result returns the empty array.

```
i = 1
loop do
  result = call_to_api(i)
  do_something_with(result)
  i += 1
  break if result.empty?
end
```

Of course in a production scenario  you want something a little more robust, including exception handlers, some progress log reporting, and some kind of concrete iteration limit to ensure that the loop does not become infinite.

**Update**

Here's an example using a class to wrap up the logic.

```
class Api
  DEFAULT_OPTIONS = {:start_position => 1, :max_iterations => 1000}

  def initialize(base_uri, config)
    @config = DEFAULT_OPTIONS.merge(config)
    @position = config[:start_position]
    @results_count = 0
  end

  def each(&block)
    advance(&block) while can_advance?
    log("Processed #{@results_count} results")
  end

  def advance(&block)
    yield result
    @results_count += result.count
    @position += 1
    @current_result = nil
  end

  def result
    @current_result ||= begin
      response = Net::HTTP.get_response(current_uri)
      JSON.decode(response.body)
    rescue
      # provide some exception handling/logging
    end
  end

  def can_advance?
    @position < (@config[:start_position] + @config[:max_iterations]) && result.any?
  end

  def current_uri
    Uri.parse("#{@base_uri}?page=#{@position}")
  end
end

api = Api.new('http://somesite.com/api/v1/resource')

api.each do |result|
  do_something_with(result)
end
```

There's also an angle with this to allow for concurrency by setting the start and iteration count for each thread which would definetly speed this up with the concurrent http requests.

Comment: One flaw with this solution, though, is that I need to keep track of the number of iterations (because I need to go from page1, 2, 3,...).

Comment: The obvious solution is just to add `i = 1` before the loop, and `i += 1` towards the end of the loop, before the `break`. But..that seems inelegant. It works, but inelegant. Any other solution?

Comment: Like i said, this is only an example. If I were using this in a real scenario I would probably wrap the code up in an class and provide an iterator, I'll add a basic example.

Answer (score 0):

Hmmm. You can get 100 items at a time, and start at a particular page. How to implement the iteration depends on what you want to do. Let's suppose that you want to collect all the unique tags. Establish a map (for example, a HashMap), then retrieve one page at a time and process it. When you hit a page that's empty, you're done.

```
// Implements a map and methods to update it
MyHashMap uniqueTags;
// Stores a page of tags
Page page;
Do
    // get a page of tags
    page = readTags();
    if (page != null) {
        uniqueTags.getUniqueTags(page);
    } else {
        break;
    }
until (page == null);
```

Comment: This should be in ruby, what would the code look like - given my `update_tags` method in my question. Your answer is hard to read.